# LAN visibility and network sharing

Tags: 10.10, networking, configuration, sharing, lan

I have two Ubuntu machines with wifi network cards configured as DHCP interfaces.

machine1:

```
inet addr:192.168.168.105  Bcast:192.168.168.255  
Mask:255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.168.252
```

machine2:

```
inet addr:192.168.168.104  Bcast:192.168.168.255  
Mask:255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.168.252
```

They are connected to the router:

```
inet addr: 192.168.168.252
```

Internet connection from the router is accessible on both of the machines.

How to share files between those two?
I have already tried few ways (eg. samba), but it looks like the machines are not visible to each other:

```
@machine1$: ping 192.168.168.104
From 192.168.168.105 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

What do I need to configure? Apparmor? Firewall?

Comment: The term `configured as DHCP interfaces` is not correct. You should say that each Ubuntu system get its network configure from the router at 192.168.168.252 using DHCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only other problem here might be the WIFI controller.  Sometimes these are configured to isolate clients.  In other words, you can browse the internet, but you are forbidden to see anything in the *same* subnet as you - this is the default on many Cisco systems and an option on draytek and presumably others.

If you have access to the WIFI gateway, check for node isolation.

Answer (score 0):

try to ping 192.168.168.104 from machine1

you are configuring 192.168.168 network, but ping 192.168.1 one (check the 3rd octet) these are different networks

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo in my question. I pinged the 168 octet and it is unreachable.